# calendarList.insert 404

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using the `NodeJs` client and I would like to add a calendar to the calendarList.

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert?apix_params=%7B%22colorRgbFormat%22%3Atrue%2C%22prettyPrint%22%3Atrue%2C%22alt%22%3A%22json%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D) doesn't give a javascript example, so I tried this.

```
createCalendar() {
    return google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth: this.googleAuthConfig()})
        .calendarList
        .insert({requestBody: {}})
}
```

This produces a 404 response, looking deeper into the `gaxios` call the 404 response happens when visiting the following

```
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList"
method = "POST"
```

I have also tried it in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert?apix_params=%7B%22colorRgbFormat%22%3Atrue%2C%22prettyPrint%22%3Atrue%2C%22alt%22%3A%22json%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22id%22%3A%22%22%7D%7D). and a 404 is returned as well.

How can I insert a new Calendar into my Calendar list using the javascript google apis?

Comment: From `I would like to add a calendar to the calendarList.` and [the official document](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert), I think that in this case, the calendar ID is required to be added in the request body. But in your request body, it is not used. How about this? By the way, which do you want to achieve your goal using Node.js or Javascript?

Comment: In the explorer they add an empty id, it still 404s.  I also attempted putting my own ID, which also 404'd.

Browser or node, the API should be the same

Comment: Thank you for replying. At first, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. At the method of "CalendarList: insert", when the calendar ID is not used, such error occurs. Although, unfortunately, I cannot understand about `my own ID`, when the invalid value is used as the calendar ID, the error occurs. For example, when `primary` is used, the error of `Invalid resource id value.` occurs. Please be careful this. By the way, I couldn't understand about the language you want to use. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Oh, I understand now.  I'm supposed to insert an existing calendar (Created with Calendars).  I had thought that this was the Calendar insert method.  If you answer the question I'll mark it correct

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At [the method of "CalendarList: insert"](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert), when the calendar ID is not used, such error occurs. When the invalid value is used as the calendar ID, the error occurs. For example, when `primary` is used, the error of `Invalid resource id value.` occurs. In this case, please use the existing calendar ID. Please be careful this.

When you want to insert new calendar, please use [the method of "Calendars: insert"](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert). The sample scripts are as follows.

#### Sample script for Node.js:

```
const calendar = google.calendar({ version: "v3", auth });
calendar.calendars.insert({
  resource: {summary: "sample title"},
})
.then(({ data }) => console.log(data))
.catch(({ errors }) => console.log(errors));
```

#### Sample script for Javascript:

```
gapi.client.calendar.calendars.insert({
  summary: "sample title"
})
.then(res => console.log(res))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

#### References:

- [CalendarList: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/insert)
- [Calendars: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert)